# Retreaving all images attached to current post

Tags: wp-query

I am trying to retrieve attachments that are attached to my current post. This is the code that I am trying to use. What I'm attempting to do is query all of my posts that are of custom post type business-manager. From within that loop I am starting another query to retrieve the attachments associated with that post. If I var dump the $attachment variable I get an empty array. If I pass the array for attachment variable into get_posts($args) then do a var dump I can retrieve all of the images. How can I do this using a new WP_Query object?

```
$my_query = new WP_Query( array(
           'post_type'         =>  'business-manager',
           'posts_per_page'    =>  1,
           'tax_query'         =>  array(
               'taxonomy'      =>  'business-type',
               'field'         =>  'slug',
               'terms'         =>  'featured'
           )
    ) );


$attachment = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => $my_query->post->ID
) );
```

Comment: Without further tests … did you try `$my_query->posts[0]->ID`?

Answer (score 1):

From [get_media_items](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_media_items) function [and his code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-admin/includes/media.php#L0), you can use [get_children](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children) adding mime type for images:

```
$images = get_children( array( 'post_parent' => $post_id, 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'orderby' => 'menu_order ASC, ID', 'order' => 'DESC') );
```

That will get you an array ($images) of images attached to $post_id. In you case, if you're inside a loop, $post_id should be equal to $post->ID

Not exactly a WP_Query implementation as you asked for, but it's easy.

If you still need the WP_Query way, you can use your own code i think (not tested). Inside a loop:
`$attachment = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_parent' => $post->ID
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_mime_type' => 'image'
    ) );`